# Question about F1 database (view or table)?

Tags: sql, mysql

i'm developing a website about Formula 1 and im building a database to store information.
In the database there are these table:

- Driver (idDriver, name, surname),

| idDriver | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Charles | Leclerc |
| 2 | Max | Verstappen |
| 3 | Lewis | Hamilton |

- Race (idRace, idSeason, name),

| idRace | idSeason | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Silverstone |
| 2 | 1 | Austria |
| 3 | 1 | Monza |

- Season (idSeason, year),

| idSeason | year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024 |
| 2 | 2023 |
| 3 | 2022 |

- RaceResult (idDriver, idRace, points, position, team).

| idDriver | idRace | points | position | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25 | 1 | ferrari |
| 2 | 1 | 18 | 2 | redbull |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | 3 | mercedes |
| 1 | 2 | 18 | 2 | ferrari |
| 3 | 2 | 25 | 1 | mercedes |
| 2 | 2 | 15 | 3 | redbull |

There are other tables but are not fundamental for my question.

My question is: if i need to show a table of the standing of a Season with the position, the driver and the total points scored, i need to create a table in the database

- ChampionshipResult (idDriver, idSeason, position, points)

| idDriver | idSeason | position | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 43 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 40 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 33 |

The column points for the rows with idSeason=1 and with idDriver=1 is the sum of all the points in the column 'points' of the table RaceResult where idDriver=1 and the idSeason of the race, identified by the idRace in RaceResult table, is 1.

and every race i add in the db update the table with the new sum of points in the row of the driver; i need to use the query create view where the total points are the sum of the points scored by every driver in every race of the championship?

I hope to be clear on what i need.

Comment: Don't post that as a comment. Edit it into your question.

Comment: What is the logic to create the results? It looks identical to the `RaceResult` table? Also `Race` has `idSeason` column but your data is missing that and has `idChampionship` instead.